# How to validate presence on model with specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I update all fields in table where the record value is null with `validate_presence_of` without write all fields one by one?

Comment: Could you please rephrase you question and elaborate the problem?

Comment: Kindly elaborate more, by giving examples and sample code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like default values? Easiest way is to set defaults in your database

```
add_column :posts, :excerpt, :text, :default => "No excerpt available"
```

`validates_presence_of` only checks if a value is present or not.

Optionally, you can set a `before_validation` hook:

```
before_validation :set_values

def set_values
  attributes.each do |attr|
    self.send("#{attr}=".to_sym, 'Default value') if attr.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use validations for that purpose. Validations are only run when an object is somehow saved or updated to the database so if you already have a bunch of records in a table and then write a validation afterwards, it will not affect the existing database records at all. Unless you try to update them again.

However, if you want to update a bunch of records with one database query them you can use a method call update_all. It could look something like this:

```
Record.update_all "value = 'default_value'", "value IS NULL"
```

Comment: Refer this for more info http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class